# is there any member named std vector iterator operator ==?

Tags: c++, stl

I can't compile this:

```
//cygwin g++ 4.9.2
std::vector<int> v;
std::vector<int>::iterator i;
i.operator==(v.begin()); //error: ...has no member named 'operator=='
```

someone please let me know what is going on.

Comment: `==` is for comparing.  You could do `i == v.begin()`, but that wouldn't really make any sense since `i` is uninitialized and you aren't saving the return value.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: AFAIK, the only requirement is that `it1 == it2` works, not that there's a member.

Comment: Was it really necessary to swear? You couldn't put your question across any other way?

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit `hell` is swearing now? If that grinds your gears, you are going to hate the rest of the internet.

Comment: @Coda17: This is a community for enthusiasts and professionals. It is not the school playground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And why did you assume, that such member function exists? Comparison operators don't have to be a member functions.

It can be defined as global function as well:

```
template <class T>
bool operator(typename vector<T>::iterator left, typename vector<T>::iterator right)
{
    //...
}
```

In your case, this may not necessarily work:

```
i.operator==(v.begin());
```

while this will always work:

```
i == v.begin();
```

Also, if you **really** want to use such unnatural syntax, you can call it this way:

```
operator==(i, v.begin());
```

But note, that result could be quite unpredictable, as you don't initialize `i`.

Comment: everyone thanks! i couldn't think of ::operator==(...)!!

Comment: If I recall correctly, `std::vector<...>::iterator` is even allowed to simply be a typedef for a pointer, since a pointer satisfies all the requirements of a vector iterator. I don't know if any implementation does this, but for one that does, even the syntax `operator==(i, v.begin())` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, there isn't.

There is a free function that takes two such iterators.

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::vector<int>::iterator i;
    operator==(i, v.begin()); // OK
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d86a855e856ffb6))

Just invoke `==` in the normal manner, and make that `i` refer to something while you're at it!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect that to work?

`std::vector::iterator` is a [Random Access Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator), which must be comparable with `==` (i.e. must be [Equality comparable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/EqualityComparable), like all [Input Iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator)), but does not need to have a member `operator==`. Non-member suffices.